# Change Bar Chart Design [iOS Charts]

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I've created a BarChart using `BarChartView` from [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) but I can't figure out how to change the bar design.

The design I am using is seen on the right side of the image whereas I need to achieve the left side design.

[image: lr]

```
@IBOutlet weak var charts: BarChartView!

charts.chartDescription?.enabled = false
charts.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
//charts.maxVisibleCount = 10
charts.drawBarShadowEnabled = false
charts.legend.enabled = false

let xAxis = charts.xAxis
xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
xAxis.labelTextColor = .white
charts.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
charts.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
charts.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
charts.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
charts.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
charts.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0 ///
charts.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0
charts.fitBars = true
charts.legend.textColor = .white

charts.setBarChartData(xValues: time, yValues: data, label: "Bar Chart")
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share some code of your current implementation?

Comment: please check i've updated the post. @Grumme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to change the bar design in the way you want.

However, someone did try a similar thing by changing the grid line to draw over the bars but it wasn't added.
See: [Added drawGridLinesOnTopEnabled boolean flag to draw grid lines on top of Bar Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/pull/2390).
You can check out his work [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/pull/2390/commits/8e55d88c3aab741442528aa157cedbe836f92e06).

Another manual workaround, although not the best but should work if you absolutely need it, is by putting a transparent view with non-transparent lines on top of the `chartView` (or any other `UIView` for that matter)

#### Example:

```
class HorizontalLines: UIView {        
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        //number of parts to divide the height of view by
        let segments = 20

        //number of lines ignoring the bottom most line
        let numberOfLines = segments - 1

        //draw the lines from left to right
        for i in (1...numberOfLines).reversed() {
            let multiplier = CGFloat(i)/CGFloat(segments)
            let y = rect.size.height * multiplier
            let startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:y)
            let endPoint = CGPoint(x:rect.size.width, y:y)

            let aPath = UIBezierPath()
            aPath.move(to: startPoint)
            aPath.addLine(to: endPoint)
            aPath.close()

            //line width
            aPath.lineWidth = 1

            aPath.stroke()
            aPath.fill()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
let lineView = HorizontalLines()
lineView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
lineView.backgroundColor = .clear

lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
chartView.addSubview(lineView)

lineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: chartView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
lineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: chartView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
lineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: chartView.topAnchor).isActive = true
lineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: chartView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

---

Be aware that this will draw a line over anything shown on the `chartView`.
So if you decide to show bar data label, then the lines would draw over that as well.

I hope this helps you in some way :)